# cant convert input from hashmap to json

Tags: java, rest-assured

I am getting following error with my restassured and testng framework.
the problem is with hash map but i dont know how  to solve it

```
    public static HashMap map = new HashMap();
    @BeforeClass
    public void iHaveADataToRegisterWith() {
        map.put("id", GenerateRandomData.getId());
        map.put("username", GenerateRandomData.getUsername());
        map.put("firstName", GenerateRandomData.getFirstName());
        map.put("lastName", GenerateRandomData.getLastName());
        map.put("email", GenerateRandomData.getEmail());
        map.put("password", GenerateRandomData.getpassword());
        map.put("phone", GenerateRandomData.getphone());

      
        baseURI = ("http://localhost:12345/api/v3/user");
        
    } @Test
    public void registerUserWithThatData() {

                given()

                .accept(ContentType.JSON)
                .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .body(map)
                .when()
                .post()
                .then()
                        .log().all()
                .statusCode(200);
    }
}
```

//Error is this one

```
{
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Input error: unable to convert input to io.swagger.petstore.model.User"
}

java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed.
Expected status code <200> but was <400>.
```

Comment: just updated . error is 
{
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Input error: unable to convert input to io.swagger.petstore.model.User"
}

java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed.
Expected status code <200> but was <400>.

Comment: Well that's the deserialization message, at least show the User class you're expecting.

Comment: Can you please briefly say how to show User class?

Comment: @user554505 Did you miss `userStatus` field? I compare your code to this api docs https://petstore.swagger.io/#/user/createUser

Comment: No userStatus is not required

Comment: @user554505 Please, add `userStatus` then reply. I don't see any clue that say `userStatus` is optional. https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-petstore/blob/1e0831732ee927238bc5de46607befc2401e18e4/src/main/java/io/swagger/petstore/controller/UserController.java#L47